# TestNG doesn't show line number for line from where the null pointer exception occurs

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

TestNG shows null pointer exception but does not show the line number from where this exception occured - difficult to debug.

Environment: Eclipse Oxygen, TestNG downloaded from eclipse marketplace.

Tried configuring the Class in run configurations but of no use.

FAILED: testSaveWithoutBackend
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ServiceAction.save(ServiceAction.java)

I expect the standard way of error to be shown using the line numbers. Here the line numbers are missing it only says exception occured in save method.

Comment: Make sure in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ the checkbox _Add line number attributes to the generated class files (used by the debugger)_ is checked.

Comment: I have done that, it was already enabled, I disabled, cleaned and again enabled but it didnt help..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which of this worked.

But I followed

1. Project > Properties: Java Compiler the checkbox Add line number attributes to the generated class files (used by the debugger)
2. Manually updated the core.prefs file in .settings folder to set org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate

After which I right clicked and refreshed the project. Thats when things started working